# IOS: how to build data containers different from table views?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to improve the look of my existing app; it uses a lot of boring UITableViews while i would like to show data horizontally in grids whose look can be customized in a more pleasant look; what can i do to use components like these? Do i have to design from scratch or are there components that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/), they have alot of Custom UI Controls for iOS and Mac OSX available.